# Rscript warning message

Tags: r, terminal, warnings, rscript

I have the following script called making_list_313_SNPs_from_csv.R. Briefly, this script takes in a .csv file and does some quick re-arrangements to produce a .txt file.

The .csv has 8 columns and the column I am interested has names like : 1_11100_A_T.

My R script looks like so:

```
library(tidyr)

setwd("/Users/m/folder/List_313/")

list = read.csv("file.csv")
list = as.data.frame(list[,2])
colnames(list) = c("SNP")

new_list = separate(data = list, col = SNP, into = c("part1", "part2", "part3", "part4"), sep = "_")
new_list = new_list[,c(1,2)]

write.table(new_list,"list_313_to_find.txt",quote=F,row.names = F, col.names = F)
```

I wanted to run this script from my Mac terminal like so:

```
 Rscript making_list_313_SNPs_from_csv.R
```

This works and I get an output file that looks like what I want. However, I get the following output:

```
Warning message:
package ‘tidyr’ was built under R version 3.2.5 

Warning message:
In .doLoadActions(where, attach) :
  trying to execute load actions without 'methods' package
```

The first warning is simply a warning about the version of the R package I am using.  However, I have no idea what the second warning means. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rscript doesn't load the methods package.  Add `library(methods)` to your script.  A normal R session loads it automatically.

If you think this is silly then you're not the only one.